# Save dialog creating a pdf

Tags: java, jsp

I've a jsp who calls a servlet that create 'on fly' a pdf.

```
  public class HelloWorld extends Action
  {
     public static final String RESULT= "C:\hello.pdf";

     public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     {
        try {
           new HelloWorld().createPdf(RESULT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           return mapping.findForward("Failure");
        }
        return mapping.findForward("Success");
     }

     public void createPdf(String filename) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
        document.open();
        PdfPTable table = createTable1();
        document.add(table);
        document.close();
     }

     public static PdfPTable createTable1() throws DocumentException {
        ...
     }
  }
```

I'd like to have a message box like 'Save As' instead of the static path `C:\hello.pdf`

Comment: The **name** of the file could be set in a text field **before** the servlet is called, and its value will be retrieved through the *ActionForm*. The **path** of the file will be determined **after** the servlet is called, when the client receives the response and deals with the binary file (the user will then choose to open or save the file).

Comment: Are you sure you are not mistaking what the server does with what the client (browser) does? Don't you want the save dialog on the client side? In your example the file is save on the server disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of create a FileOutputStream, you could create your pdf in memory using a buffer output stream, then you can use your jsp to return your pdf as a binary file and let your browser handle it (showing the save as window).

Your jsp code will be something like (assuming you will have a byte[] representing your PDF file):

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"filename.pdf\"");
response.setBufferSize(pdf.length);
response.setContentLength(pdf.length);
response.getOutputStream().write(pdf);
```

Be sure not to write any character before these instruction in your response.

Hope this helps,
Regards

Comment: Thanks I took the hint and modified for my purpose but it was so helpfull.